# How to extract from an arrray of arrays one single value

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I have an Array of Arrays as below.
The arrays are grouped by nation so you see one Array with Arrays with same nation like below example "United States of America".

My issue is how in JS to extract only once "United States of America" and use it as a text.

The arrays are always coming in order per nation of the User and then I would like to have the nation name as a text from that array.

So the first array nation is always the country name we want to use as a text.

I tried to do so with find but not good:

```
data.find(locale => locale[...]);
```

I also tried to use `map` but I receive all the country names back instead of one value.

I'm new in this field and would like to get how to do it.

```
[
  [
    "USA1",
    "New York",
    "New York",
    "United States of America",
    "411 Pearl St, New York, NY 10038, USA",
    "ACTIVE"
  ],
  [
    "USA2",
    "New York",
    "New York",
    "United States of America",
    "411 Pearl St, New York, NY 10038, USA",
    "ACTIVE" 
],
[
 [
   ... ,"SWEDEN", ....
 ]
],
```

As requested:

[image: data]

Comment: You mean `data[0][3]`?

Comment: is the name of the nation always the fourth element in the array?

Comment: Yes are always in the same order and the suggestion doesn't ´data[0][3]´
Uncaught TypeError: can't access property 3, data[0] is undefined

Comment: The example array is not valid, could you update it?

Comment: This array is what I'm receiving in the system I'm working, why is invalid?

Comment: What is the exact shape of the data you are receiving?

Comment: I'm adding a screenshot from console.log

Comment: Please check my screenshot @AlanOmar

Comment: Have your problem solved? Is there anything I can add to my answer?

Comment: Yes seems the solution here are working need to test it better more

Answer (score 1):

can you try this solution to see if it works:

```js
let data=[["USA1","New York","New York","United States of America","411 Pearl St, New York, NY 10038, USA","ACTIVE"],["USA2","New York","New York","United States of America","411 Pearl St, New York, NY 10038, USA","ACTIVE"],["USA1","New York","New York","Sweden","411 Pearl St, New York, NY 10038, USA","ACTIVE"],["USA2","New York","New York","Finland","411 Pearl St, New York, NY 10038, USA","ACTIVE"]];


let result = [...new Set(data.map(e => e[3]))]

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want all the unique country names from the two-dimensional array, where the country name is always the 4th element of the inner array.

**This solution is consists of two parts**

1. Loop through the array, get all country names. (4th element of the inner array, `data[i][3]`).
2. Filter the results to get the unique values only.

**Working example**

```js
const data = [
  [
    "USA1",
    "New York",
    "New York",
    "United States of America",
    "411 Pearl St, New York, NY 10038, USA",
    "ACTIVE"
  ],
  [
    "USA2",
    "New York",
    "New York",
    "United States of America",
    "411 Pearl St, New York, NY 10038, USA",
    "ACTIVE"
  ],
  [
    "SWEDEN",
    "City",
    "State",
    "Sweden"
  ]
]

const getUniqueCountries = () => {
  let countries = data.map((country) => country[3])
  let uniqueCountries = countries.filter((country, i, arr) => arr.indexOf(country) === i)
  return uniqueCountries
}

console.log(getUniqueCountries())
```

**More information**

[.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) [.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) [.indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)

Answer (score 1):

This is the quickest solutions that you can use to extract any specific value

```
const array = [
            [
                "USA1",
                "New York",
                "New York",
                "United States of America",
                "411 Pearl St, New York, NY 10038, USA",
                "ACTIVE"
            ],
            [
                "USA2",
                "New York",
                "New York",
                "United States of America",
                "411 Pearl St, New York, NY 10038, USA",
                "ACTIVE" 
            ]
        ]
        console.log(array[1][2])
```

**Result:**

```
New York
```

Comment: This solution on the second [...] whatever number I put is giving undefined
If i try array[1][2] I got undefined

Comment: You need to check your array, because, the format of array that I shared above is same as you shared in your question, and It works fine, or you might check `if(array.length) { /*place your code here*/ }`